# postscript hyperlink url auto-open

Tags: pdf, automation, ghostscript, postscript, ps

I'm trying to add a hyperlink to a PDF by modifying the PostScript.

Any possible to open this action link automated or opening postscript or pdf. it will be executed the link.

```
[/Rect [ 0 425 295 445 ]
 /Action << /Subtype /URI /URI (http://www.adobe.com/) >>
/Border [ 0 0 2 ]
/Color [ .7 0 0 ]
/Subtype /Link
ANN pdfmark
```

Comment: You shouldn't do that. Documents should not try to connect to the internet unasked.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Could you make it a bit more clear what you want to achieve? The second sentence of your question is not clear to me. Do you want the PDF to follow the link immediately after is has been opened?

Answer (score 2):

Though not recommended, it is possible to associate this type of action ("`/S/URI`") with the page-open event of a PDF page in order to be automatically executed.

However, not every PDF viewer may support it. Tested with Acrobat Reader. Typeset with `latex`, `dvips`, `ps2pdf`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
Note: Opening the next page of this document will take you to an external web page.

\newpage
Page with \texttt{URI} action on page-open event. This may not work in viewers other than Acrobat Reader.
\special{ps: mark {ThisPage} <</AA <</O <</S/URI/URI (http://www.adobe.com/)>> >> >> /PUT pdfmark}
\end{document}
```